# sql query to manipulate strings

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have table named "path" with a single column named "path file name" and it contains something like this below:

```
1. U:01.03.141878Box1819P3FarihaTanzir(Moniruzzaman)0103141(756).jpg
2. U:01.03.141876Box1807P3Arif(Mahfuz)151213Picture 96609.jpg 
3. U:01.03.141130Box1781P3RakhiSwpna(Farah)0103141 (1486).jpg 
4. U:01.03.141952Box1810P1Sufia(Jakia)010314Picture 25304.jpg
```

I want to get the names within the first braces() like: 1.Moniruzzaman 2.Mahfuz 3.Farah 4.Jakia

I have used combination of patindex(), charindex() and substring function with left and right but could not get the desired result.

Comment: CHARINDEX(REVERSE(string)) should help get the rightmost ) and (, after which a simple SUBSTRING will get your results.  Note that () are "parenthesis" - braces are {}.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the query you tried.

Comment: Is it always the first set of parenthesis that contains your desired item?

Comment: i have used a query like : SELECT 
    CASE WHEN CHARINDEX('(', [path file name])>0 
        THEN LEFT([path file name], CHARINDEX(')', [path file name])) 
    ELSE [path file name] END [path file name] into [names]
FROM( 
    SELECT 
        CASE WHEN CHARINDEX(')', [path file name])>0 THEN
            REPLACE(RIGHT([path file name], CHARINDEX(')', REVERSE([wallet])) - 1), ')', '') 
        ELSE [path file name] END [path file name]
    FROM 
        [path]
)x

Answer (score 1):

Here is a method that uses `stuff()` twice:

```
select stuff(stuff(col, charindex(')', col), len(col), ''),
                   1, charindex('(', col), '')
```

You can test it by adding:

```
from (select 'asbc(axx)asfdsf(123)d' as col) t
```

This assumes that the first closing paren (`)`) appears after the first opening paren (`(`).

Answer (score 1):

Try this :-

```
Declare @var varchar(100) 
Set @var ='U:01.03.141878Box1819P3FarihaTanzir(Moniruzzaman)0103141(756).jpg'

Select substring(@var,
                charindex('(',@var)+1,
                                   charindex(')',@var)-charindex('(',@var)-1)
```

[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d41d8/15454)